# How does the Val() function in VB.NET work?

Tags: vb.net, sorting

I have an assignment in VB.NET that I'm stuck with at the moment. Would love some help.

The question is this: You enter random characters into a textbox, for example 12ab3c4d5efgh, and at the click of a button, it must sort the characters in the textbox into 2 separate Labels, depending on whether or not the 'character' is a number or letter. So, continuing the example, Label1 must show '12345' and Label 2 must show 'abcdefgh'. I hope I made myself clear enough.

I was asked to use the Val() function but I really have no clue. Could someone please help? :D

Comment: If you want some help about `Val()` take a look at here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/k7beh1x9(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Val would return 12345, it just get the numeric characters out and converts them to an int. you could them convert that back to a string and use it to filter the original string. Don't know why anyone would bother though, solving the problem properly would be much easier and far more comprehensible.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson, (`Val("12ab3c4d5efgh")` returns `12.0`.

Comment: Hmmm, even less use them isn't it...

Answer (score 2):

This creates one string with the digits and one with the letters. Characters that are not digits or letters are ignored.

```
Dim chars As String = "12ab3c4d5efgh"
Dim nums As String = chars.Where(Function(c) Char.IsDigit(c)).ToArray 
Dim lets As String = chars.Where(Function(c) Char.IsLetter(c)).ToArray
```

Comment: I was thinking on those lines, but I'm a C# boy, so I was about to look up the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use `Val()` something like this would do. But be careful: `Val("0")` also returns `0`.

```
Dim numbers As String = String.Empty
Dim letters As String = String.Empty
Dim sourceString As String = "12ab3c4d50efgh"

For Each c As Char In sourceString
    If Val(c) = 0 And c <> "0" Then letters &= c Else numbers &= c
Next

Console.WriteLine("Numbers: " & numbers)
Console.WriteLine("Letters: " & letters)
Console.ReadKey()
```